# Remote users unable to search site

Tags: search

I am new to Sharepoint, and was tasked with getting a Sharepoint list ready for a global team to make updates to. The list was to be used by a group in the same domain but in a different country. The list was created on SharePoint Online.

Initially, the users were able to search the contents of list using the Search in the left navigation bar which was needed as opposed to the "Filter by" for the Column requires them to select each list item they would like to search for. This is cumbersome if you have manually select 30 names when you are searching in a list of 7000 names. Basically, something that would allow them to pull up a list of companies beginning with a certain name.

Couple days after the list was shared with the User group with "Edit" rights, they lost the ability to search using the left navigation bar. This coincides with the List Name change that was done by one of the admins; the permissions were unchanged but their ability to search was impacted.

Some of the users are only able to see the items they made edits to but we know for sure there more items beginning with the name we were searching by.

The following troubleshooting steps have been taken but haven`t resolved the issue:

1. Adding users to the Owner Group
2. Re-indexing the Site
3. Having the users login from my machine
4. Creating a new group with Edit rights and adding the users to the new group
5. Verification that the group type is Sharepoint (based on a MSFT technology forum post that was similar to this issue but they seemed to attribute the issue to users being in Office365 groups)
6. Adding the user to the site directly as an individual with Edit rights

Any suggestions to help resolve this would be really appreciated. Many Thanks.